# Format Array Data to JSON_ENCODE using php

Tags: php

I am formating an array data into `Json_encode` using php. This array data is from my database. I have described how I am doing  it here

```
$pens=$db->fetchAllPens();  //This fetches the list of pens
$a = array();
$response = array();

$response["success"]="true";

while ($pen = mysqli_fetch_array($pens)) {    
    $response["label"]["id"]=$pen["ID"];
    $response["label"]["name"] = $pen["name"];

    array_push($a,$response);
}

    echo json_encode($a,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

The above code gives me the below output

```
[
{
    "success": "true",
    "label": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "nimble"
    }
},
{
    "success": "true",
    "label": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "lopsel"
    }
}
]
```

However I am expecting an output below

```
{
"success":true,
"label":[
    {
        "id":1,
        "name":"nimble"

    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "name":"lopsel"

    }
]
}
```

Please is there a way to achieve the desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$pens = $db->fetchAllPens();  //This fetches the list of pens
$response = array('success' => true, 'label' => array());

while ($pen = mysqli_fetch_array($pens)) {    
    $response['label'][] = array('id'   => $pen['ID'],
                                 'name' => $pen['name']
                                );
}

echo json_encode($response,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

You are writing to the wrong variable in each loop cycle.

Instead do the following:

```
while ($pen = mysqli_fetch_array($pens)) {
  $data[] = [
    'id' => $pen['ID'],
    'name' => $pen['Name'],
  ];
}

$response['label'] = $data;

echo json_encode($response,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

Start by putting the `status` directly into the `$a` array.

Then place the rows data into `$a['label'][]` i.e. a new occurance of the `$a['label']` array

```
$pens=$db->fetchAllPens();  //This fetches the list of pens
$a = array();

$a["success"] = "true";

while ($pen = mysqli_fetch_array($pens)) {    
    $response = array();

    $response["id"]     = $pen["ID"];
    $response["name"]   = $pen["name"];

    $a['label'][]       = $response;
}
echo json_encode($a,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Result:

```
{
    "success": "true",
    "label": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "fred"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Bill"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: For the effort. All answers are equal but with a slight difference.

Comment: That is true, and I was suppose to accept only one as an answer, anyways kindly check this question out if you can be of help http://stackoverflow.com/q/42762250/2595059