# Http Client variables returns null after posting to php server

Tags: android

I am sending data to mysql database using android app(java)  and transferring it with php. I am using `HttpClient` to post it. Below is a snippet of the Http Client which is being done on the Async Background.

```
EDIT : This is how I am posting the the variables content

  ...
  HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("url", "../register");
        map.put("id", id.getText().toString());
        map.put("name", name.getText().toString());

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(image)) {
            map.put("picture",image);
        }
       new MultiPartRequester(activity, map,1, this);
   ...
```

This is the transmitter

```
...
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urls[0]);
            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(
                    httpclient.getParams(), 200000);

            MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder
                    .create();

            for (String key : map.keySet()) {

                if (key.equalsIgnoreCase(Params.Image)) {
                    File f = new File(map.get(key));

                    builder.addBinaryBody(key, f,
                            ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, f.getName());
                } else {
                    builder.addTextBody(key, map.get(key), ContentType.create("text/plain", MIME.UTF8_CHARSET));
                }


            }
            httppost.setEntity(builder.build());


            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(
                    response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

            return responseBody;

    ...
```

Now, the client above works well, but upon receiving it on the php file, the variables returns null. This is how I receive it with php.

```
 <?php 
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $name=$_POST['name'];

    $response["success"]="true";
    $response["id"]=$id;
    echo json_encode($response);


   //The print out
  response :{"success":"true","id":"null"}
 ?>
```

Is there something I am really doing wrong, I would be grateful for your help. Regards!

Comment: `$response["success"]="true";`?? Why are you blindly crying for success?

Comment: Nope, it is just for testing purposes

Comment: You are not showing which variables/parameters you send. So how can we ever comment?

Comment: Well specially for testing you should not blindly set success to true. You are not seriously debugging.

Comment: @greenapps, I believe the success refers to integration debugging - the request has been sent, sent to correct server, server is up and running, it handles the request, and returns valid json.

Comment: You should start using the function isset() in youf php script. And echo() accordingly.

Comment: It still returns null

Comment: @greenapps I was even trying to use `var_dump($_post) ` but that also returns null

Comment: It should be var_dump($_POST). That will never return null but display an empty array. Please edit your post so we can see how you use isset().

Comment: Buh I think that function was just to check if array is empty or not? it is not to resolve my main issue

Comment: No. Indeed. But as long as you have messy php code you know nothing. Make your php robust. And you talked about null. Now what is it? Null or empty?

Comment: Why are you hitting on me that way? Have you seen my full php script? You haven't  and you are just jumping into conclusions! I posted a simple php script, just to make everyone understand my problem! So why the insults, if you can't help just don't comment on my question again!

Comment: `So why the insults, ` ??? Where? Now what is it? Null or empty?

Comment: It gives an empty feedback

Comment: Your code works for me. (I removed adding a file. And checking if a file is added. And the MultiPartRequester).